# How to set First Dropdown value as default for first line in grid then Second value defaults from second line in grid

Tags: acumatica

In the Product drop-down, there are  2 values, First value (Product) will default for first line only and Second value (Co-Product) will default from the second line.

I tried this in FieldDefaulting event

```
    protected void TSFormulaProdsNCoProds_Product_FieldDefaulting(PXCache cache, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = (TSFormulaProdsNCoProds)e.Row;
        if (row == null)
            return;
        if (TSFormProdsNCoProds.Select().Count == 0)
        {
            e.NewValue = "P";
        }
        else
        {
            e.NewValue = "C";
        }
    }
```

Can anyone provide a suggestion to me?

Comment: Try to replace condition in the if with `TSFormProdsNCoProds.LineNbr==1` or something like that. Also what is the problem with you code?

Comment: When I click on the plus(+)  to add new row values are not defaulting on "product" Field .if I select any another field or control then default values are coming

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have `PXDefault` attribute decorated at `DAC` level. In that case, you need to set `Cancel` flag to prevent execution of `FieldDefaulting` event handlers that are defined in attributes.

Example :-

```cs
protected void TSFormulaProdsNCoProds_Product_FieldDefaulting(PXCache cache, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
{
    var row = (TSFormulaProdsNCoProds)e.Row;
    if (row == null)
        return;

    e.NewValue = (TSFormProdsNCoProds.Select().Count == 0) ? "P" : "C";
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

This is explained in `Example 5.2: Inserting a Default Detail Data Record` of `T200 Acumatica Framework Fundamental course`.

[image: T200-Example 5.2]